# Can I extend the session length for my Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've created a Service Account so that Appfigures could connect and get data.

The issue is that we have to verify our Google Play account every week in Appfigures and they
have told if we can extend the session length to avoid having to relink every so often and the usual default set up is 14 days and if we know what our limitation is set up  with at this time.

I've reviewed the console, I've looked in the help but I haven't found anything about this.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

In the following documentation you will find how to [Set session length for Google Cloud services](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9368756?hl=en).